# [Paradox]How can Gödel prove that Gödel sentence is unprovable but true, if such proof itself proves that Gödel sentence is true?

Tags: logic, intuition, incompleteness, meta-math

Isn't the proof that Gödel sentence is unprovable but true a proof itself that Gödel sentence is true?

Gödel in the preface of his proof remarked:

> “From the remark that [the unprovable statement] asserts its own unprovability, it follows at once that [the unprovable statement] is correct, since [the unprovable statement] is certainly unprovable (because undecidable). So the proposition which is undecidable in the system PM yet turns out to be decided by meta-mathematical considerations.”

My question may be the example of what Gödel called "meta-mathematical considerations". It is hard to understand that the proposition which is undecidable in mathematics can be decided by meta-mathematics. What could be the explanation for this apparent paradox?

Comment: The proof that the sentence is true relies on the fact that the theory is *consistent*.

Comment: But such proof does not rely on the fact that the theory is complete

Comment: The proposition is not undecidable in "mathematics", whatever that means. It's undecidable *inside first-order Peano Arithmetic*, which certainly is not the whole of mathematics.

Answer (score 9):

Godel produces a sentence $\varphi$. What Godel proves is that - **assuming $PA$ is consistent** - $\varphi$ is true but not provable in $PA$. (I'm assuming the theory we're looking at is "PA," here - but we can of course replace $PA$ with any sufficiently strong recursively axiomatized theory, such as PM, ZFC, NF, ...)

This proof goes through perfectly inside the theory $PA$. There's no contradiction, though, because - in order to conclude that $\varphi$ is true - $PA$ would have to know that $PA$ is consistent. So, instead of a paradox, we get Godel's **second** incompleteness theorem: that, if $PA$ is consistent, $PA$ doesn't prove "$PA$ is consistent."

---

I'm being ahistorical here - in fact, what Godel proved was slightly weaker, and Rosser was the one who brought the hypothesis down to "$PA$ is consistent" - but this is the meat of the situation.

Comment: The assumption that the theory in question is consistent may seem silly - **of course** these theories are consistent. That's a very dangerous assumption, though - sure, we're all (probably :P) convinced that $PA$ is consistent, but how surprised would you *really* be if ZFC+"there is a proper class of I0 cardinals" was proved inconsistent tomorrow? I'd be surprised, certainly, but fine (whereas, if $PA$ were found inconsistent, my health insurance might get a workout :P). Somewhere there's a "boundary of plausibility", but - don't take consistency for granted!

Comment: Yes, many of us would be extremely schocked if $PA$ would be proven inconsistent, but although logical foundations of mathematics rely on constistency of $PA$, mathematics is more than theorems of first (or second) order theory. We have millenia of physically (empirically) proved mathematics worth. What I want to say is that most key theorems of mathematics wouldn't fall with hypothetical fall of $PA$.

Comment: What does it mean "true" here? If it is unprovable in PA, than there exist a model of PA where $\varphi$ is false, or am I wrong?

Comment: @PeterFranek "True" in this context means "true *in the standard model of $\mathsf{PA}$*," that is, true in $\mathbb{N}$ itself. As you say, by the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) there are models of $\mathsf{PA}$ where it does not hold.

Answer (score 5):

You changed "undecidable in the system PM" into "undecidable in mathematics" in your paraphrase and so the explanation is that **you** introduced the apparent paradox.

[Aside: the quotation is correct in saying "PM" rather than "PA": Gödel’s original paper on the incompleteness theorem deals with the system of Russell and Whitehead's [Principia Mathematica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principia_Mathematica) and not Peano Arithmetic.]

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, it does demonstrate it, but it does not prove it within a formal axiomatic system.  It can only be concluded outside that system, so there is no paradox.

What Gödel's theorem actually asserts is that there is at least one proposition that is true but which lacks a proof *within a particular axiomatic system*.  He was responding to *Principia Mathematica*, but the technique he employs can be applied "against" any sufficiently strong axiomatic system.

Therefore, the fact that one can conclude, *outside* that axiomatic system, that the proposition is true does not produce a paradox, does not disprove the proposition.

Comment: This is totally correct, but it might suggest that Godel's theorem is *unformalizable*. Let me just comment that this would be false - appropriately stated, Godel's theorem can be proved in, say, PA, to which it applies. No contradiction occurs, though, because of the hypothesis of the theorem - see my answer.